# get the two array elements on either side of a specific array element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like:

```
myArray <- array
    Image <- array
        0 <- array
            id - 850
            name - someimagename
        1 <- array
            id - 763
            name - alandscapepic
        2 <- array
            id - 567
            name - imageofbuilding
        3 <- array
            id - 376
            name - picname
```

and so on. Note that the actual id's of the images aren't in any particular order.

When I'm viewing the image who's id is 567, for example, I want to be able to know the information on either side of where ever in the array that image_id actually is.

**EDIT**

I'm trying array_search like this:

```
array_search(array('id'=>$id), $currentFolder['Image']);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So if the key for that item in the `Image` array is `2`, you want to know how to access the items at keys `1` and `3`? Isn't this solvable by simply subtracting or adding `1` to the key value? Can you show code on how you are currently trying to do this and specify where specifically you are having a problem?

Comment: I've edited my post - I can't figure out how I can get the id I want because it's not like 0=>678, 1=>876 etc... it's 0(id=>876), 1(id=>876) etc...

Comment: So your problem is actually getting the key for the item you are currently viewing then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function to get the index of subarray and + or - 1. e.g:

```
$id=567;

$index=false;

foreach ($currentFolder['Image'] as $key=>$value){
  if (in_array($id, $value)) {
    $index=$key; // <--- get the indexOf subarray
    break;
  }
}

echo $index;
//  if not false    
// $currentFolder['Image'][$index + 1];
// $currentFolder['Image'][$index - 1];
```

Comment: No problem. Need to be mentioned. 1. Check if the index==0 OR index==MAX_IN_YOUR_ARRAY. 2. You cant have more than one 567s in the subs because this function will stop at the first id=>567. @Zaphod Beeblebrox